# Local Network file sharing issues - Windows 10 - Unable to open read only "someone else is working in"

Tags: windows-10, office365, excel-2016, network-share

Small office with 2 computers.
Folder of files shared locally - and on 1 of the PC's is backed up to One Drive.

If the file (Excel) is open on the PC1 which has the files - and the user on PC2 tries to open the file the error message:

***Someone else is working in "Network Path and filename" right now. Please Try again later.***

Can this file not be opened in Read Only Mode? Tried pressing Shift and right clicking and opening in read Only Mode but the same error message appears.

If the file is opened on PC2 first and the user on PC1(with the files) tries to open the file - they can open it no problem and view the file and even add new data, it is only when they try to save the file they are warned -

***We can't save file because the file is read-only. To keep changes you'll need to sabe the workbook with a new name or in a different location.***

Can this user not be warned when opening the file that it is read only. Using Excel 2016 in this case.

Comment: Why not to [share the file using OneDrive](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/collaborate-on-word-documents-with-real-time-co-authoring-7dd3040c-3f30-4fdd-bab0-8586492a1f1d)? Then you could simultaneously edit a document on both PCs.

Comment: Already tried that method - constantly ran into issues with sync conflicts. then once user unable to sync files

Comment: Simply avoid editing same fragment of the document. I've been using this feature for months and I had no issues with conflicts. And everything is reversible from the cloud.